# .gitIgnore file for asp.net core web application

Tags: git, asp.net-core

I'm making a website and pushing to a repository to share with my friend so that he can review/critique, and he got on my case for not using a git ignore file.

What are some of the universal folders to ignore in a git commit?
Can someone give me an example file?

Answer (score 7):

Check out this site for a full description:

```
https://www.gitignore.io/
```

It will supply you with a full list of ignored file